# How to stop whatsapp autoplaying next voice message?

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app

When there are several voice messages loaded in the chat, clicking play on an earlier one will cause:

1. The voice message you clicked on plays to the end
2. The voice message you clicked on is stopped
3. the player time of the message you clicked on is reset to the beginning
4. The chat automatically scrolls to centralise the next voice message in the chat
5. This next voice message in the chat begins playing automatically

I would like to stop (4)and (5) from happening. I don't mind if (3) doesn't happen anymore as a result.

It's jarring the have the whole chat out of my control flying up and down, and the player times end up in funny positions I don't want them to be in because of play/pausing chaos. It's hard to hit the play/pause buttons in self-scrolling chats. I would rather the chat stay still, and I would like to have the option of relistening to the voice message that just finished if I want to. It's stressful when a new audio I didn't initiate starts playing on its own.